# How to promote the "include script with your question" to newcomers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, new-users

Many of the questions, in Stack Overflow, I have seen the new users are not posting part of there script with their question or they fail to post their attempt at getting the script working

How can it be promoted for users to post their script for the rest of us to comment / work on to get a working peace of script?

Maybe have it as part of the Question submitting page?

Comment: I think this question may be better asked on Meta SO but we address it for coding questions at [gis.se] by having a custom close reason that says working code snippet expected and code attempt at minimum.

Comment: Thanks, for the comment and suggestion. Will post on meta.so

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/NoCode